# Spivak, Ch. 22, Problem 7b: Can we assume a sequence has a limit to show what the limit is, or must we first prove that it converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The following is a problem from Chapter 22 "Infinite Sequences" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 7. In Problem 2-16 we saw that any rational approximation $k/l$ to $\sqrt{2}$ can be replaced by a better approximation
>    $\frac{k+2l}{k+l}$. In particular, starting with $k=l=1$, we obtain
>
> $$1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{5},\frac{17}{12},...$$
>
> (a) Prove that this sequence is given recursively by
>
> $$a_1=1$$
>
> $$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_n}$$
>
> (b) Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\sqrt{2}$. This gives the
> so-called *continued function expansion*
>
> $$\sqrt{2}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+...}}$$

The solution manual proof of $(b)$ is interesting but a bit long and complicated.

The following is an attempt at the proof. It assumes that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=l$ and uses the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n}$.

$$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_n}=\frac{2+a_n}{1+a_n}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=l=\frac{2+l}{1+l}$$

$$l+l^2=2+l$$

$$l=\sqrt{2}$$

This proof assumes that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}$ exists. This seems fishy. Is it the case that we must prove that ${a_n}$ converges before we can use the above proof?

Comment: The argument shows that if the limit exists it must be $\sqrt{2}$. But it doesn't show that the limit exists, so you still have to prove that.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, please could you prove that the limit of the sequence exists ?

Comment: $$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le {1\over 4}|a_n-a_{n-1}|$$ Thus the series $\sum(a_{n}-a_{n-1})$ is convergent, The partial sums are of the form $a_n-a_1$

Comment: While tricks like Ryszard Szwarc gives are nice when you can find them, the most useful tools for proving that sequences in $\Bbb R$ converge are (1) if the sequence is increasing, and is bounded above, it must converge. And the same for decreasing sequences. (2) if the sequence is Cauchy, it must converge. (3) if there are sequences $a_n \le b_n \le c_n$ and you already know that $(a_n)$ and $(c_n)$ both converge to the same value $L$, then $(b_n)$ also converges to that value.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I would have used $(1)$ but $a_n$ is neither increasing nor decreasing. It can be proved that $a_{2n-1}$ is increasing and $a_{2n}$ decreasing, which is suficient for getting convergence.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc - I think your method is fine. I just wanted to point out the standard tools and show how they could also be used in this case. I was writing up essentially the same thing in second comment, but was distracted, so I hadn't posted it yet. That is using the even and odd monotonic sequences, which converge by (1), to the same number by the argument the OP gave (slightly modified), and sandwich (with repeating entries) the full sequence, proving convergence by (3).

Comment: Spivak's solution is the one mentioned where we consider the two subsequences formed by the odd and even indexed elements of the original sequence.

Comment: @evianpring Was my answer helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting my answer? Please comment if my answer can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 5):

In order to assert the limit of a sequence, we must know that sequence has a limit in addition to show what is the possible value of the limit.

Here is an example of what can happen when we have not proved a sequence has a limit. Let the sequence be $-1, 1, -1 , 1, \cdots$, i.e., $s_1=1$, $s_{n+1}=-s_n$. Had we assumed the sequence has a limit, we could have let $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_{n+1}=\ell$ and used the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_{n}$, computing

$$\begin{aligned}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_{n+1}&=-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_{n}\\
\ell&=-\ell\\
\ell&=0\end{aligned}$$
It would have been absurd had we claimed that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n=0$.

Similarly, for sequence $1,3,7,15,\cdots$, i.e., $t_1=1$, $t_{n+1}=2t_n+1$, we could have computed $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} t_{n+1}=2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}t_n+1$, claiming $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} t_{n}=-1$. Note "the limit" obtained would be $-1$ always even if we set the first term $t_1$ to any other number.

---

Here is a way to do part (b).

It is obvious that $a_n\ge1$ for all $n$ by induction on $n$.

Consider $d_n=|a_n-\sqrt2|$.
Then $$d_{n+1}=
\left|\frac{2+a_n}{1+a_n}-\sqrt2\right|=\left|\frac{(1-\sqrt2)(a_n-\sqrt2)}{1+a_n}\right|\le \frac12d_n$$
Hence, $0\le d_n\le(1/2)^{n-1}$ by induction on $n$.  So $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}d_n=0$, i.e., $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sqrt2$.